# rpm spec file syntax error

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I was trying to create a rpm package, my spec file looks like this:

```
%define config_option (cat %1)
%define __spec_install_post %{nil}
%define debug_package %{nil}
%define __os_install_post %{_dbpath}/brp-compress
%define __prelink_undo_cmd %{nil}
%define __strip /bin/true

Name: %{rpm_name}
Summary: ASG-RP32 Rootfs
Version: 1
Release: 1
License: xxxx
Group: rootfs
Vendor: xxxx
BuildRoot: %{rpmroot}
Prefix: /

%description
See Summary.

%install
mkdir -p /home /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /selinux /srv /sys /tmp

%files
%defattr (-, root, root)
/README
/bin/*
/boot/*
/dev/*
/etc/*
/lib/*
/lib64/*
/sbin/*
/usr/*
/var/*
```

but the output gave me some error,

```
Processing files: pkg-linux-x86-32-linux-xc-release-1-1
getOutputFrom(): Broken pipe
```

please help.

NOTE: The the directories after install are existing dir, when I tried using %dir to include them, they give me the same error as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get details of the cause of the error by executing the rpmbuild command with the -vv option.

If the error occurs while executing `check-files` script, you can add the following definition to the spec file as a temporary solution.

```
%define __check_files %{nil}
```

BTW, are you sure that you want to make directories under / directory but $RPM_BUILD_ROOT, as defined in %install section?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try.

About the mkdir part, I was trying to use 
    %dir 
to include the empty dir, but seems that's not working, however, with check_files %{nil} defined, I will try using %dir instead of making directories in install section.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hmm, after define the check files to {nil}, then use %dir still got the same `getOutputFrom(): Broken pipe` error.

`%dir
/home
/media
/mnt
/opt 
/proc
/root
/selinux
/srv
/sys
/tmp`

Comment: Where is actually the %{rpmroot}? Could you let us know the complete spec file?